# How to create a Folder with Google Drive REST AP and HTTPClient?

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using Google Drive REST  API with HTTPClient to create a folder. 
The REST API is document [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert#try-it)  Please note that the REST AP Request executes -- but uses the wrong data: tt creates a new file called "untitled" and puts my json there.

I have tried different methods of building the POST request with HTTPClient which execute successfully -- but somehow the Google Drive responds with creating a file  and returns this data and ignores POST data that I submit.

This is what the server reponds with
..

"kind": "drive#file",
"id": "0B-fYJN-c4UDjUlh1TUZadF9vejA",  this is a valid ID
"title": "Untitled",   ----wrong title
"mimeType": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",  -- this is the wrong mimeType
..

I have tried the following ways of invoking the API : I am not sure what is happening  to the data I am sending with the post.

1) Using form name value pairs

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?key="+GoogleClientConstants.GOOGLE_api_key);

postRequest.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
postRequest.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");


List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("title", "vip"));
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mimeType", "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"));
postRequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, org.apache.http.Consts.UTF_8 ));
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
```

2) Using StringEntity

```
JSONObject jo= new JSONObject();
jo.element("title", "pets").element("mimeType", "application/vnd.google-apps.folder");



ContentType contentType= ContentType.create("application/json", Charset.forName("UTF-8")) ;
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jo.toString(), contentType); 

logger.info(" sending "+ jo.toString());


postRequest.setEntity(entity);


HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
```

In both cases , Google API responds  with 200 and the above mentioned returned FileResource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created a little example, using your code. And for me everything works OK. Please, see my source code:

```
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

public class SourceCodeProgram {

    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(
                "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files");
        post.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        post.addHeader("Authorization",
                "Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

        JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
        jsonObject.addProperty("title", "Test folder");
        jsonObject
                .addProperty("mimeType", "application/vnd.google-apps.folder");

        post.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString()));
        httpClient.execute(post);
    }
}
```

Above code doesn't throw any exception. I've checked my Drive and I can see 'Test folder' in it. What the key are you putting in post URL?

Why are you not using [Google Drive Client Library](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-java) in your app?

Comment: Your answer solved the problem. I was using the wrong URL : please see this page  - https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert . I was using the URL listed here for POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files  -- this was wrong. You used the correct post URL and solved  the issue.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. But I'm interesting, why are you not using Drive API client library, which Google Team wrote?

Comment: please see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15986911/how-to-use-google-drive-client-library-for-java-with-my-homegrown-oauth-2-framew

Comment: I am trying to do this with HTTPURLConnection without luck. DefaultHttpClient should not be used anymore as the Android Documentation points out.

Comment: Where is the problem in your case? What do you receive as a response from the API?

Answer (score 0):

To create a SUBfolder you have to use the ID(s) of the parent folder(s), for example to create the folder "sub" in a parent folder "super" that has ID XXX:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files
Authorization: Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}
Content-Type: application/json
...
{
  "title": "sub",
  "parents": [{"id":"XXX"}]
  "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
}
```

To create root folders, you can obmit the "parents" argument

Comment: That is not quite correct -- If you try this api here with Firefox firebug or Chrome dev tools https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert#try-it , you will note that you can create folders without  passing parent's info and the folder would be created in the root folder. The issue is the somehow data passed by HTTPClient is not getting to the server or is in the wrong place.