# How to use Google Drive Client Library for Java with my homegrown OAUTH 2 Framework for web application?

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-oauth

My web application already does OAUTh authentication successfully with Facebook, LinkedIn, Google etc. using REST and/or signpost-oauth library.

So once I already have ACCES_TOKEN from GoogleAPIs server using my web app , I want to use Google Drive Client to access files etc.

This is the google Drive example but it relies upon using Google authorization code flow ( which I can't understand well enough to use with my Java EE web app  )

```
 // authorization
 Credential credential = authorize();
 // set up the global Drive instance
 drive = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
     .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
```

How do I change this to use  ACCESS_TOKEN  and other credentials that I have already obtained through my web application's  OAUTH framework ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you already have an Access Token, you can simply do this:

```
Credential credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(yourAccessToken);
```

If you have an Access Token AND a Refresh Token, which is **much** better since you can get automatic token refresh from the client library, you should do this:

```
Credential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
    .setClientSecrets(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
    .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
    .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
    .build()
    .setAccessToken(yourAccessToken)
    .setRefreshToken(yourRefreshToken);
```

Also Check the [GoogleCredential Javadoc](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.8.0-beta/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredential.html) for more examples.

Comment: I tried a lot for 3 days to create credentials object in other ways. But this one worked fine. Thank you very much @Nivco.