# Authorization for Google Drive Push Notifications for Java

Tags: java, google-drive-api, resttemplate

I am trying to get push notifications from a resource on Google Drive to my server. I have been looking at this example:

```
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push
```

And I have tried translating that to Java into something like this:

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
    map.add("id", "36d00d08-000d-4723-91bc-a1a6ec302e59");
    map.add("type", "web_hook");
    map.add("address", "https://mydomain.appspot.com/rest/drive");
    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(map, headers);
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(uri, request, String.class);
```

I have previously been using Googles libs for Drive to access files. In those cases I didn't need to create the request in such a "manual" way. I have used the class GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow with a token to authorize my requests. I'm not sure how I should do that with RestTemplate. I am guessing that I need to do something like:

```
headers.set("Authorization", X);
```

What should X be here? Is that even the right way to approach authorization?

Edit:

Here is my attempt by reading a secret. The result is HTTP 401:

```
 @Override
    public String startListening() throws IOException {
        final String fileId = "omitted";
        String uri = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + fileId + "/watch";
        HttpHeaders headers = getHeaders(getSecret());
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(getProperties(), headers);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(uri, request, String.class);
        return response.getStatusCode() + " " + response.getBody() + " " + response.getHeaders();
    }

    private static HttpHeaders getHeaders(String theString) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + theString);
        return headers;
    }

    private static MultiValueMap<String, String> getProperties() {
        MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
        map.add("id", "some uid");
        map.add("type", "web_hook");
        map.add("address", "https://mydomain.appspot.com/rest/drive");
        return map;
    }

    private static String getSecret() throws IOException {
        InputStream in =
                ConcreteDriveListenerFactory.class.getResourceAsStream("/drive_secret.json");
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        IOUtils.copy(in, writer, "UTF-8");
        return writer.toString();
    }
```

Comment: the access token probably

Comment: I read my access token(a token that is working when using Google Drive's 3rd party client that sadly doesn't support push) and put into the header. Didn't help. Could it be something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DalmTo has mentioned, X is for token. With regard to sample POST request for Drive API try this code snippet from this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975674/how-to-create-a-folder-with-google-drive-rest-ap-and-httpclient). It also uses a POST method.

```
public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(
            "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files");
    post.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    post.addHeader("Authorization",
            "Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
    jsonObject.addProperty("title", "Test folder");
    jsonObject
            .addProperty("mimeType", "application/vnd.google-apps.folder");

    post.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString()));
    httpClient.execute(post);
}
```

Comment: Didn't have any luck when trying this, maybe because this is referring to v2 of the API, or something else?